# Redirect /?q= through .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

It seems that there are hundreds of bots crawling and spamming my WordPress site contact forms. Obviously they are trying to crawl Drupal related urls such as:

```
/?q=user
/?q=node/add
/?q=user/register
```

When so they are redirected to my homepage and abuse the contact form found there.

Is there a way to forbid access to urls like /?something through htaccess?
I was thinking for redirecting them to 0.0.0.0 but I couldnt find any htaccess expression to help me achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do something like this. If the query string matches, it will get a forbidden.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(.*)
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Or all query strings, but be careful.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Just came here to +1 otherwise sleeping :)